# Uninstalled container view's embed segue performed

Tags: ios, ios8, uicontainerview, adaptive-ui

I have a container view not which is not installed on iPhone, but installed on iPad. But the embed segue is performed in iPhone anyway. I use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to prevent it but I am not sure it is the best way. Because container view is still in the view controllers view hierarchy (i think).  What is the best or recommended way to prevent the embed segue to be performed? Or not letting uninstalled view to be loaded.